# solving for matrices

Tags: matrices

Suppose that

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}3 & 2\\\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

Find all real numbers $\lambda$ such that (A − λI2) multiplied by

$$(A - \lambda I)\begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2\end{pmatrix} = O$$

has a solution which is not $x_1 = x_2 = 0$.
Such real numbers, $\lambda$, are called eigenvalues of $A$ and the non-zero solutions are called eigenvectors of $A$. Please don’t use determinants.

this is one of my worksheet question in which are not marked for the week however im stuck I have used $A − \lambda I$ to obtain $$\begin{pmatrix}3-λ & 2\\\ 1 & 1-λ\end{pmatrix}$$. would I now multiply to get a linear simultaneous equation but this cant happen as the answer is a $2x2$ matrix which would not fit this any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have some knowledge about when a system of linear equations has more than one solution?  Apply that here.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably a typo and means $0_{2\times 1}$ not $0_{2\times 2}$. So solve $\begin{pmatrix}3-\lambda&2\\1&1-\lambda\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\end{pmatrix}$.

We get the system of equations $(3-\lambda)x+2y=0,x+(1-\lambda)y=0$. Solve the second one for x and return it in the first equation, to get $(3-\lambda)y(\lambda-1)+2y=0$. Do some manipulations to get $y(-\lambda^2+4\lambda-1)=0$. Apply the quadratic formula to solve for $\lambda$:

$$\begin{split}\lambda&=\frac{-4\pm\sqrt{16-4}}{-2}\\
&=2\mp\sqrt 3\end{split}$$